# mediaelement.js video dont work with safari

Tags: mediaelement.js

mediaelement.js videos doesnt load and show loading image forever even in the main video in the player website http://mediaelementjs.com/

this is happening  with me in safari 5.1.7 for windows 
my system is windows 7 64bit

i have already installed quicktime and that wasnt  the problem

i tried to remove every thing  , the video work fine if its pure html5 video tag , but when linked it to mediaelement library it refused to load and the loading image continue rotating infintley

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the full URL as source, not only the path:

http://www.example.com/path/to/video.mp4 instead of path/to/video.mp4

Comment: thanks for your answer , unfortunately i left the project since that time ,  but  i will try you answer next time when  facing same issue

Comment: I tried this suggestion but it had no effect. My problem browsers are Safari on Mac, and Firefox on a single user's PC (waiting for further browser info).